# How to view changes made to a texture with Nodes, in Blender Render?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to edit a texture with nodes, in blender render mode.

And I would like to see what my nodes are doing to the texture.

I think I need a viewer node for that, but it wont work.

Or is the only way to view my changes is to re-render the scene?

Im following [this tutorial](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/nodes/types/converter/math.html#theory)

[image]

Comment: Your changes should be visible on **Material** and **Render**shading on the viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your changes should be visible on **Material** and **Render** shading on the 3d [image]viewport

Comment: So the unedited version should be visible in the texture viewport shading, and the edited version should be visible in Material/rendered viewport shading? Mine goes blank in material viewport shading but the rest works. Im guessing that means the viewer node isnt meant to work in blender render. Thank you for your time.